# mongoose query Regex with special characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to search values having special characters such as "(" in a document.
I 'm using following criteria in mongoose and fetch the names that matches like "abc (pvt) ltd".

```
 var criteria = {};
 criteria.name = new RegExp(searchPrameters.name, "i");
```

Comment: Could you further explain what isn't working, and what was expected ?

Comment: when I search strings like "abc (pvt) ltd" that does not retrieving. eventhough it is in the Data base.

Comment: Because chars are parsed as a regexp. If you want to search chars literally, use some lib that escapes regexps. There's a bunch of them.

Comment: can u explain wih a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with replacing of the parenthesis using string.replace() function.

```
 searchPrameters.name = searchPrameters.name.replace('(','\\(');
 searchPrameters.name = searchPrameters.name.replace(')','\\)');
```